# AutoMapper How do I Merge two parents into a single object & reverse

Tags: automapper

I've been doing some reading but this seems little different OP.  Three objects:

parent1 and Parent2 are a 1:1 relationship.  "Owned" in EF-speak, both have same Id key

```
public class parent1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public int field2 { get; set; }
}

public class parent2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string field3 { get; set; }
    public int field4 { get; set; }
}

public class myDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public int field2 { get; set; }
    public string field3 { get; set; }
    public int field4 { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a short and simple way of merging these two parents together and breaking them apart when the DTO comes back in using AutoMapper?  Other than specifying each property individually.

CreateMap<parent1, myDTO>();
CreateMap<parent2, myDTO>();

is fairly straightforward but I wanted to avoid things like

Mapper.Map<parent2, myDTO>(source2, Mapper.Map<parent1, myDTO>(source))

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to avoid a double call to Map is to encapsulate both parent classes into one. That could make sense, as parent1 and parent2 are 1:1, so virtually they represent a single object.

```
public class mergedParents
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public int field2 { get; set; }
    public string field3 { get; set; }
    public int field4 { get; set; }
}
```